# After creating classList.toggle('active') you try to apply CSS, but it does not work

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

It is verified that classname is created using classList.toggle ("active").
However, css cannot be applied with the generated class name.
For your information, CSS used CSS module.
If you try code execution by tags classname will be applied well.
However, css does not apply to class names created in that tag.

JS

```
    const menuList = document.getElementsByClassName(styles.menulist);
    const onClick = (e) => {
        // menuList.classList.toggle("active");
        menuList[0].classList.toggle("active");
      };

<header className={styles.nav}>
      <img src={logo} className={styles.logo} alt="mondayoff" />
      <ul className={styles.menulist}>
        <li className={styles.menu}>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.menu}>
          <Link onClick={scrollByAbout}>About</Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.menu}>
          <Link onClick={scrollByGame} className={styles.gameClick}>
            Game
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.menu}>
          <Link to="/article">Article</Link>
        </li>
        <li className={styles.menu}>
          <Link>Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <input className={styles.check} type="checkbox" id="burger-check" />
        <label
          className={styles.icon}
          id="icon"
          for="burger-check"
          onClick={onClick}
        >
          <span className={styles.sticks}></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
   @media all and (max-width: 599px) {
  .nav {
    flex-direction: column;

    height: auto;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  .menulist {
    margin-right: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self: center;
    display: none;
  }
  .active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .menu {
    margin-right: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
  .menu a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .container {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2rem;
    top: 1.8rem;
  }

  .icon .sticks {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
    width: 50px;
  }

  .icon .sticks:before,
  .icon .sticks:after {
    background: white;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .icon .sticks:before {
    top: 10px;
  }

  .icon .sticks:after {
    top: -10px;
  }
  .check {
    display: none;
  }

  .check:checked ~ body {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .check:checked ~ .icon .sticks {
    background: transparent;
  }

  .check:checked ~ .icon .sticks:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }

  .check:checked ~ .icon .sticks:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .check:checked ~ .icon:not(.steps) .sticks:before,
  .check:checked ~ .icon:not(.steps) .sticks:after {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I don't know why it can't be applied in this situation. Please help me.

Comment: So you want to trigger `active` class or to verify if it exists?

Comment: The goal is to show navbar after toggle.At this time, classname is created after toggle, but css is not applied to the classname created. I hope the menuist's display changes from none to flex, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide more context for your code?

Comment: I modified the post now.Please check.

Comment: Check your screen width, I see that you are having media query at `max 599px`

Comment: I'm working on max-width (599px) with mediaQuery. So I'm making the screen size at 599px.

Comment: .menulist.active{display:flex} This CSS does not apply. We have confirmed that the tag has a class name called active.

Comment: Check that element if the CSS is there?

Comment: I don't know why not. I think I've done everything I can, but I can't answer it.
I also saw that classname was created when I saw the tag as console.log().
I checked it on YouTube, and I found out that it works the way it's done.

Comment: im having the exact same problem in Chrome on desktop recently. never remember this being a problem before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS modules generate new class names from the ones in your CSS file in order to scope them to a particular component.

The result of this is a javascript object like the following:

```js
import styles from 'Styles.module.css'

console.log(styles)

/*
Which would output something like this:

{
  active: 'Active_7AC34'
}
*/
```

You are using the string literal `"active"` instead of the value generated by the CSS module. What you should do instead is this:

```js
const menuList = document.getElementsByClassName(styles.menulist);
const onClick = (e) => {
  menuList[0].classList.toggle(styles.active);
};
```

Comment: @oldboy I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Would you mind elaborating?